# Watchkit complication click action

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I have written an Apple Watch app with a complication that works well. But I often accidentally click on that complication, and it opens my watch app.
Is there some attribute to tell the complication that there is no action when I click on it?

As an example, the sunrise/sunset complication has no click action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There is no `ClockKit` feature which would stop it from launching your app when you (inadvertently) tap your complication.

You can, however, slide your finger away from your complication, which will deselect it, and avoid opening your app.

*You can get a feel for this by long pressing your complication, which will indicate that it's selected.  If you slightly swipe away from it, it will deselect itself.  If you swipe too far, you may bring up a glance or notification.*

Apart from deselecting the complication, I'm not sure that there would be a way to handle any inadvertent-versus-intentional interaction, where you might not want the app to be launched.  If you can come up with a case, you should [submit a feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to Apple.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I don't fully understeand how to slide away from complication :).

Comment: Instead of lifting your finger up when you inadvertently tap your complication, slightly swipe up or down to move your finger away from the complication.  Now the complication is no longer selected, and when you lift your finger off the screen, nothing will happen.  You can deselect it in the same manner as a button or a tableView cell that you inadvertently touch.